# Magento 1.8. How to add one customer in two or more groups?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

Magento 1.8. 
How to add one customer in two or more groups ?
Magento 1.8. 
How to add one customer in two or more groups ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of by default magento does not provide this type functionality.

If you want do that you can do using this hack method

***Note that it is not standard method to achieve this and i am not sure how it behaves when shopping cart rules apply***

First of all go to your `database` and click on the `eav_attribute` table and then find for `group_id` in the `attribute code` field and edit this record.

change `frontend_input` from `select` to `multiselect` // *it will allow you to select multiple group of customer*

then

change `backend_type` from `static` to `varchar`

From this way you can select multiple customer group,*But if you want to display multiple customer group in customer grid then you have to follow this*

From

```
/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Renderer/Group.php

<?php
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Renderer_Group
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract {
public function render(Varien_Object $row)
{
$value = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
$groups = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('customer_group_id', array('in' => explode(',', $value)));
$groupNames = array();
foreach ($groups as $group)
{
$groupNames[] = $group->getCustomerGroupCode();
}
return implode(', ', $groupNames);
}
}
```

Then override

`/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php` (copy it to `/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php`)

In the `_prepareColumns()` function

```
$this->addColumn('group', array(
'header'    =>  Mage::helper('customer')->__('Group'),
'width'     =>  '100',
'index'     =>  'group_id',
'type'      =>  'options',
'options'   =>  $groups,
));
```

to this

```
$this->addColumn('group_id', array(
'header'    =>  Mage::helper('customer')->__('Group'),
'width'     =>  '100',
'index'     =>  'group_id',
'type'      =>  'options',
'options'   =>  $groups,
'renderer' => 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Renderer_Group',
'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_filterGroupCondition')
));
```

then it will use that class for rendering groups on the grid.

Also in the `_prepareCollection()` function, around line 52 find `->addAttributeToSelect('group_id') and add after: ->addAttributeToSelect('customer_group_id')`

Having multiple groups per customer also seems to interfere with tiered pricing (where a product has a different price depending on customer group). To fix that on the frontend display... Fix for customer group-based product pricing tiers when calculating on the front-end:

In `/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Price.php` Around line 138,

FIND:

`$customerGroup = $this->_getCustomerGroupId($product);`

ADD AFTER:

```
 $customerGroups = explode(',',$customerGroup);
```

FIND:

```
if ($groupPrice['cust_group'] == $customerGroup && $groupPrice['website_price'] < $matchedPrice) { REPLACE WITH: if (in_array($groupPrice['cust_group'],$customerGroups) && $groupPrice['website_price'] < $matchedPrice) {
```

Do the same thing in `/app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Model/Product/Price.php` if you use bundles.

I do not yet have a fix for displaying the customer group tier price when creating an order or reorder from the backend dashboard - they just show up the standard product prices.

Finally, when figuring all this out we did have some instances where `catalog_product_entity_group_price` got emptied and I'm still not sure why it happened, so do make sure to take backups. For that table I restored it from an SQL backup, but re-indexing things and maybe flushing the Magento cache is also often required when getting into this stuff.

When doing things such as searching for customers by group programmatically in your own scripts or modules you may have to take into account that it is now a multiselect for example by doing things like this:

```
$allowedGroups = array(
array(
"finset" => array(10)
),
array(
"finset" => array(42)
)
);
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addFieldToFilter('group_id', $allowedGroups);
```

Although I'm not sure that that piece of code will work right until all the customers have rows in the `customer_entity_varchar` table which is where the new value for a customer's groups is stored when there are more than one group selected. Only a single group ID remains stored in `customer_entity` as that field isn't `varchar`.

Let me know if you have any query

Comment: @Keyur : Please let me know how you handle sales and catalog promotion,help will be appreciated.